# How to add new key value pair to a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am initializing a list of dictionaries with:

```
sequences = [dict() for x in range(83)]
```

I want to be able to add `key : value` pairs to a certain dictionary. For example, I want to add the key value pair `primer 1 : primer 2` to the first slot in the list.

```
sequences[0].update({ primer1 : primer2 })
```

This gives me the error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. How am I able to access a certain dictionary within the list to add a key value pair?

Comment: is `primer1` a list?

Comment: if `primer2` is a list it cannot be a dict value. Use a tuple instead.

Comment: I think the error is complaining that the key in your dict primer1 is a list type, which is not hashable

Comment: @JDarbyshire: You've got that backwards. Dictionary values can be lists, but dictionary keys can't.

Answer (score 3):

This error message suggests that the key `primer1` is a list (or contains a list).

What you're attempting will not be possible, because dict keys must be [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html) in Python.  Instead, you may use a hashable sequence type for the key `primer1`, such as a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuples).